# VS Code Go To Implementation with ctrl/cmd left click

Tags: visual-studio-code, ide, hotkeys

Is there anyway to bind left mouse click on function to go to implementation by default instead of declaration (intelliJ allows mouse bindings for example), and also to rebind go to delcatartion to ctrl/cmd shift left click ?

I couldn't find any option for mouse bindings or even changing this hotkey configuration in vs code.

Comment: Yes, it is impossible.